# OnTriggerEnter срабатывает несколько раз

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я делал монетки в своей игре и столкнулся с такой проблемой - у моего персонажа несколько бокс коллайдеров и поэтому когда персонаж касается монеты функция OnTriggerEnter срабатывает несколько раз и начисляется несколько монет.

Вот мой код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CoinPickUP : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("coin"))
        {
            int coins = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("coins");
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("coins", ++coins);
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В принципе, гуглится несколько решений, но мне кажется самое элегантное - это добавить флаг `bool collected = false;` в объект `Coin`, выставлять его после сбора монеты в `true` и проверять в `OnTriggerEnter`, что он не выставлен. Если монета уже собрана (`collected == true`), то не заходить в логику `if`-а и не увеличивать счётчик собранных монет. Видимо, `Destroy` отрабатывает позже, чем успевает сработать несколько раз `OnTriggerEnter`. События помещаются в очередь и отрабатывают в порядке очерёдности, если триггер уже в очереди несколько раз есть, то он отработает раньше, чем выполнится `Destroy`.

Comment: Там нет Race Condition, Destroy делает так, что объект будет уничтоженным для следующего фрейма, а в текущем он остается доступным до конца выполнения скрипта. Так задумано архитектурно.